# How to integrate apache solr(4.0) to an existing spring mvc web application in Websphere

Tags: solr

I'm able to do it with manual copying of folders from solr distribution into my web app. But I feel there should be a neat way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to do with following steps.

Step-1: Added the required jars dependency in pom.xml 
         as follows..

```
    <solr.version>4.0.0</solr.version>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
        <artifactId>solr-core</artifactId>
        <version>${solr.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
        <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
        <version>${solr.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
        <artifactId>solr-velocity</artifactId>
        <version>${solr.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
        <artifactId>solr-dataimporthandler</artifactId>
        <version>${solr.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.indexer</groupId>
        <artifactId>indexer-core</artifactId>
        <version>${solr.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Step-2: Added the following mappings in web.xml

```
    <env-entry>
        <env-entry-name>solr/home</env-entry-name>
        <env-entry-value>C:\Sadhana\apache-solr-4.0.0\example\example-DIH\solr</env-entry-value>
        <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
    </env-entry>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>SolrRequestFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>Context of my webapp</param-name>
            <param-value>2</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>SolrRequestFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Zookeeper</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.solr.servlet.ZookeeperInfoServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>LoadAdminUI</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.solr.servlet.LoadAdminUiServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>RedirectOldAdminUI</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.solr.servlet.RedirectServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>destination</param-name>
            <param-value>${context}/</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>RedirectOldZookeeper</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.solr.servlet.RedirectServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>destination</param-name>
            <param-value>${context}/zookeeper</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>RedirectLogging</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.solr.servlet.RedirectServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>destination</param-name>
            <param-value>${context}/~logging</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>RedirectOldAdminUI</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/admin</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>RedirectOldZookeeper</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/zookeeper.jsp</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>RedirectLogging</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/logging</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Zookeeper</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/zookeeper</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>LoadAdminUI</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/admin.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>.xsl</extension>
        <mime-type>application/xslt+xml</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
```

Step-3: Added the following directories from solr-webapp of solr distribution into my webapp.
             1. css
             2. img
             3. js
             4. tpl
             5.admin.html, favicon.ico, Thumbs.db

Step-4: Modified the following solr configurations from the directory - apache-solr-4.0.0\example\example-DIH\solr
              1.solr.xml
              2.solrconfig.xml
              3.schema.xml
              4.db-data-config.xml
Step-5: restart the websphere and add the webapp and access the solr url using your server ipaddress:9080/contextwebapp               this will open the admin page of the solr